# What's the word that means spitting while talking?

Tags: word-request

What's the word that means spitting while talking? By that I mean emit saliva and have it flown out of the mouth in an involuntarily way while talking? I remember there was a word for it, but I don't remember what it was.

Comment: **Splutter** comes close; to make a series of short explosive spitting or choking sounds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While English is rich in vocabulary, there is no term for that in regular use. However, I did find a slang term on Urban Dictionary which fits the definition. [Gleak](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Gleak)

Comment: This sounds truly awful. Probably only known to a handful of people....

Answer (score 2):

You might try "spraying" ... when I was a kid and someone would spit while talking we'd say "Say it, don't spray it!"

From

> **spray** *v*
>   4. to scatter (liquid) in the form of fine particles
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spray)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's sialoquacious or sialoquent.

Comment: These words are at best extremely rare.  Can you provide any sources to show them in use?

Comment: [Merriam–Webster has an interesting little write-up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-for-things-you-wish-people-wouldnt-do), suggesting that these words pretty much *only* appear in dictionaries and glossaries.  Unfortunately, these words probably wouldn't be very useful for English language learners.

Comment: (Note: this is just my opinion) Is it our duty to decide whether an answer would be useful to a learner or not, considering that there are different kinds of learners and learning needs are not the same per person? I'm wondering because I am also a learner and I appreciate this answer. I think our main concern (aside from the frequency of the word use, which should be indicated) is knowing whether the word is valid or not? Or whether the references are valid or not? Or maybe we should remove word requests and phrase requests here and have them all in EL&U? :) Thank you!